# chrome.exe command line parameters for kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using chrome.exe version: 29.0.1547.66 m on a w7 pc.
I'd like to use command line parameters like --kiosk from the command prompt when starting chrome. 
I found a list of switches here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

When I type in:
chrome.exe --kiosk http://somesite.com 
Chrome starts, it opens up the specified url, but not in kiosk mode.

It seems to ignore the --kiosk command. If I try --help as a flag, it gets ignored as well.

Is this supported on chrome.exe on windows? Should the commandline interface be enabled first somehow? Any thoughts?
Thanx in advance,
Paul

Comment: Try the solution provided in [this question at SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/423272/how-to-make-chrome-open-in-kiosk-mode-even-if-theres-already-another-instance-r). It worked for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem solved ... also thanks to the post of ComFreek .... problem was about running instances of chrome.
As soon as I closed all running chrome instances before invoking chrome, the commandline options started to work.

Answer (score 10):

--chrome-frame worked for me:

```
"c:\progra~2\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --chrome-frame --kiosk http://foldoc.org/pub/misc/automata.html
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add --overscroll-history-navigation=0 to stop navigation to other sites